# Google Cloud Shell `No space left on device` even though disk not full?

Tags: google-cloud-shell

I am trying to replace my local development machine with Google Cloud Sheel. When running `yarn` on Cloud Shell, the system says I am out of space. But `df` tells me there is lots of space remaining (only 68% used on `/home`)

```
@cloudshell:~/***$ df
Filesystem                        1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
overlay                            62742040 43483680  19241976  70% /
tmpfs                                 65536        0     65536   0% /dev
tmpfs                               8200748        0   8200748   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/disk/by-id/google-home-part1   5028480  3229288   1520716  68% /home
/dev/sda1                          62742040 43483680  19241976  70% /root
/dev/root                           2006736  1012260    994476  51% /lib/modules
shm                                   65536        0     65536   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                               8200748      904   8199844   1% /google/host/var/run
user@cloudshell:~/**$ pwd
/home/user/***
user@cloudshell:~/***$ mkdir test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: No space left on device
```

Am I missing something? Why does the system say out of space when there is 32% left?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Cloud Shell documentation](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#disk_storage):

> Cloud Shell provisions 5 GB of free persistent disk storage mounted as
> your $HOME directory on the virtual machine instance.
>
> ...
>
> If you encounter a `no space left on device` error, you'll need to remove files from your home directory using the Cloud Shell terminal to free up space.

So it is possible that when it reaches a certain threshold of disk usage that message will pop up.

Answer (score -1):

If it helps anyone, I have been facing the same issue in GCP VM every now and then. I am using a Container Optimised OS and my boot disk forces this issue.

What worked for me was resizing my boot disk - [see here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-disk-full-resize). The error goes away once there's enough space.

Debugging with serial port output is also helpful here - [see here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/viewing-serial-port-output)

Comment: This is a solution for Google Cloud Compute VMs, not for Cloud Shell. This is an ephimeral Linux shell (with the option for persistent HOME directory), and drives can't be resized.